# Falta operador VBA excel - access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

Trato de enviar una Tabla "Tabla" los datos a una base de datos en access al intentar ejecutar la macro me sale lo de la imagen pero si intento importar una celda distinta si lo agarra FORMULA que hay en esa celda

```
=SI.ERROR(BUSCARV([@[N° ]];Tabla_Proveedores1[[#Todo];[N]:[Proveedores]];2;FALSO);SI([@[N° ]];"EL PROVEEDOR NO ESTA REGISTRADO";""))

Private Sub ImportarDatos_Click()
Dim conectar As String
Dim sPath As String
Dim sql As String
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection

lrow = Range("A1").Value

sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Base.accdb"

' '''Usaremos el Proveedor '12.0" ya que está habilitado para todas las versiones de Office:
conectar = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & sPath & ";Persist Security Info=False;"

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

cn.Open conectar
For i = 4 To lrow
i = i + 1

sql = "INSERT INTO historial (fecha, n, proveedor) VALUES(#" & Format(Cells(i, 2).Value, "mm/dd/yy hh:nn:ss") & "#," & Cells(i, 3).Value & "," & Cells(i, 4).Value & ")"

cn.Execute sql
Next
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
'LimpiarRegistros

MsgBox "Datos Registrados con Exito", vbInformation, "Excel a Access"

End Sub
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cualquier string que quieras insertar en una base de datos debe ir rodeado de comillas simples, así que debería quedar así la parte de la sentencia que introduce el proveedor:

```
 & ", '" & Cells(i, 4).Value & "')"
```

Y la sentencia completa.

```
sql = "INSERT INTO historial (fecha, n, proveedor) VALUES(#" & Format(Cells(i, 2).Value, "mm/dd/yy hh:nn:ss") & "#," & Cells(i, 3).Value & ", '" & Cells(i, 4).Value & "')"
```

Desconozco el tipo de dato de la columna "n", si fuera de tipo texto deberías también ponerl3 las comillas simples.

Comment: osea que todo lo que sea texto tengo que poner comillas simples? muy buena su ayuda gracias

Comment: Si, así es. Igual que con las fechas pones un #